# Is it possible to limit hibernate SQL logging for few operations like "only update" or "everything but select"?

Tags: sql, hibernate, logging, log4j2

For some reason, I want to trace SQL queries limited for only update and insert operation (full happiness when I'll be able to log everything on particular table, but I think it's impossible...). Full scope of SQL is easy to achieve:

```
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="SQLFileAppender" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="SQLFileAppender" />
    </Logger>
```

So, is it possible to do it in somewhat more complex log4j config or shall I forget about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation about filters which you can use to implement exactly this requirement: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html